# Open docs from SP2010 in excel/word crashes

Tags: 2010, excel, word

I have:

```
SP2010 rented from a company. 1 site collection
I have IE 9.0.8
```

For about a 6 months I have this consistent problem.

When I click on a Word doc or Excel doc, I get a choice to edit, I do so.

Word opens, asks for my password. I put it in, and then word crashes. This also happen with Excel.

What I do, and this is a real pain, download the doc to my pc, check out, edit doc, upload then check in.

I am not sure what the problem could be. I have tried this on, 3 PC's and 2 laptops. Same thing.

This is the error message in work:

```
roblem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   WINWORD.EXE
Application Version:    14.0.4734.1000
Application Timestamp:  4b58fafb
Fault Module Name:  mso.dll
Fault Module Version:   14.0.6112.5000
Fault Module Timestamp: 4e9b28fd
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   000000000003d657
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
Locale ID:  2057

Additional information about the problem:
LCID:   1033
skulcid:    2057
```

I thought this might be a localized error however of 3PC's and 2 Laptops, I find that hard to believe.

I have also tried to setup SharePoint Workspace, however I get a crash as well.

Thank you

Comment: what edition of SP2010 (Ent/Std/Foundation) ?

Comment: @sbc111 SP2010 Foundation

Comment: Wish I had the answer, but instead I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you have the SharePoint 2010 SP1 & Office 2010 SP1 upgrades, etc.

The issues may be addresed by

1. Adding SharePoint site to Trusted Sites zone (browser security)
2. File associations: doc, docx, xls, xlsx with Word & Excel (see links below)

[Examine File Extensions and File Associations in Win7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff687021.aspx)

[Managing file associations in Win7](http://searchenterprisedesktop.techtarget.com/tip/Managing-file-associations-in-Windows-7)

If file associations appear OK (control panel) - verify & reenter by using PowerShell or manual editing of the registry.

[UPDATE] : Dug up this post which narrows it down to Word's template and registry setting - [Troubleshooting Word -- Problems With Word's Registry Entry.](http://wordprocessing.about.com/od/troubleshootin1/qt/wordregentry.htm)

Comment: Hi, I have done number 1, and 2 is correct anyway. I still get the same thing.

Comment: It is SP2010 with SP1. A company called APPS4RENT...

Answer (score 1):

Is the webclient service running? this is required to allow opening files from the network using WebDAV.

Comment: where do I find this. Site actions > site settings >???

Comment: No it's in Windows Services. Just type "services.msc" in the search program box in the start menu if you're under windows 7 or vista. Or for XP do Start > Run.

Comment: it was not running, however I have started out. Opened up a doc and I still have the same issue. however this time it loaded the doc after putting my PSW and then it crashed.  `Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
  Application Name: WINWORD.EXE
  Application Version: 14.0.4734.1000
  Application Timestamp: 4b58fafb
  Fault Module Name: mso.dll`

Comment: Hmmm strange issue... I suppose you already try to repair Office Client? Have you tried with another computer on the same Sharepoint website?

Comment: I have tried other laptops, same thing. I have done a the repair on office 2010 but it does work with office 2007. Question - Is it possible that the vendor who is supplying the service make some error on their side?

Comment: A last thing you can check: http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/ie/fix-ie-crash-when-opening-documents-in-sharepoint/

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem also, I am running Win7, SP2013, Office 2010 and SharePoint Designer 2013. It seems that there is an issue with installing SP designer causing this same conflict. I ran a repair on Office and it seems to be working. This fix also worked for another user in the office also. Others without the SharePoint designer have not had this issue.